# How enabling AWS Classic ELB's Cross-Zone load balancing affects application performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I've two `EC2` instances running behind `classic load balancer` registered with two different `availability zones`. I am running load test on my application to come up with appropriate `scale-up policy`. Currently there's no scale-up policy set-up for my `ASG`.

By default, cross-zone load balancing is disabled. Whenever I run performance test on my application, I see that CPU utilization is not consistent and threads are killed quite frequently.

[image]

[image]

When I enable cross-zone load balancing, these graphs improve.

[image]

[image]

When I looked up ELB documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html), I found that when there are always same number of instances running in each AZ behind ELB, cross-zone enabled and disabled are supposed to work the same way.

Why am I seeing this discrepancy?

(This is a `spring-boot` application and graphs are obtained from `visualvm`)

Comment: Review your server logs, looking at the source IP of the individual ELB node that is handling each request (a private IP -- you can find these, with some digging, in the EC2 console under "network interfaces" in the left hand pane).  One potentially likely outcome is that your performance test mechanism is actually only sending requests to a single ELB node in one AZ.  They *"work the same way"* assuming each ELB *node*  receives a comparable traffic volume -- not a problem with a lot of browsers hitting you, but potentally very different when a single performance test is running.

Comment: Requests are being sent to both ELB nodes. I monitored both ec2 instances (JVMs on ec2) using visualvm. Both of them receive traffic, CPU Utilization, memory utilization and threads are seen. Both instances show sudden drop in number of threads.